# Rails how to create an initializer inside a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, initializer

I am trying to build a gem in Rails 3 and inside it i am trying to pass an initializer:

```
Credentials.configure do |config|
  file = File.read("#{Rails.root}/config/twitter.yaml")
  file_config = YAML.load(file)

  config.consumer_key = file_config[Rails.env][:consumer_key]
  config.consumer_secret = file_config[Rails.env][:consumer_secret]
  config.callback_url = URI.escape(file_config[Rails.env][:callback_url])
  config.time_stamp = Time.now.to_i
end
```

and then i am trying to call it like this:

```
Credentials.time_stamp
```

but i get this error:

```
uninitialized constant Twitter::Credentials
```

what is the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your gem will first need to define a generator in lib/generators/your_gem_name_generator.rb

```
mkdir -p lib/generators/
```

Copy your initializer in that folder with a name like `twitter_credentials.rb`

Then create another file in that folder with a name like `twitter_generator.rb` with content like this:

```
class YourGemNameRailtie < Rails::Generators::Base
  source_root(File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__)))
  def copy_initializer
    copy_file 'twitter_credentials.rb', 'config/initializers/twitter_credentials.rb'
  end
end
```

You should check out the official documentation for creating a generator here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html

Comment: But is there a way to keep a dynamic configuration file inside the gem itself?

Comment: @Wahtever Just `require` it? Re-reading the question, it seems your problem is there is no Credentials class. Have you implemented a Credentials class with a configure class method that accepts a block to hold state?