# Best way to write initializers on a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, initializer, railtie

I'm writing my first gem, and I've some issues with initializers part.

So I read about Railtie, and I'm little bit confused, there is part that talks about initializers and something on generators.

According to this thread, he suggested using generator
[Rails how to create an initializer inside a gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16004378/rails-how-to-create-an-initializer-inside-a-gem)

So I'm not sure what's the best way.

Anyway I tried to do some initializer that add some method to Jbuilder

```
module MyGem
  class Railtie < Rails::Railtie
    initializer "my_gem.jbuilder_custom_cache" do |variable|
      class JbuilderTemplate
        def custom_cache!(resource, name, &block)
          fragment_cache_key = ::MyGem::Logic.cache_key(name, resource)
          options = { expires_in: 1.hour }
          cache!(fragment_cache_key, options, &block)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This didn't work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested, but I think you can do:

```
module MyGem
  class Railtie < Rails::Railtie
    config.to_prepare do
      JbuilderTemplate.class_eval do 
        def custom_cache!(resource, name, &block)
          fragment_cache_key = ::MyGem::Logic.cache_key(name, resource)
          options = { expires_in: 1.hour }
          cache!(fragment_cache_key, options, &block)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

See here ([http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Railtie.html#class-Rails::Railtie-label-Configuration](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Railtie.html#class-Rails%3a%3aRailtie-label-Configuration)) for more information about the `config.to_prepare` block.

Comment: Thanks! It seems like to_prepare is not mandatory here.
So the way you define methods on Railtie is by class_eval.