# can I get a data from file only one time in my gem similar to config/initializers in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Yml File need to be read by My Gem from Consuming application or from my gem itself. Instead of reading for each request which increase number of IO request. I want something similar to config/Initializers/constant.rb which I used to get data only once when server gets started.

I tried same thing in ruby gem. I created one ruby file configuration.rb and stored the data as global data. It is working fine.

```
class ConfigurationData
  DATA = YAML.load(File.open(File.join('config','fallback_data','data.yml')))
end
```

QUESTION:Is There better methods to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right place to do this is in an initializer file. So add a new file to `config/initializers`. From there you can load your configuration file like this:

```
DATA = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('/config/fallback_data/data.yml'))[Rails.env]
```

`DATA` will be available in the apps context:

```
data_from_file = DATA['one_of_the_keys']
```

All this looks a little bit different, when you want to do this in a gem. When Rails loads a gem, it will start with the `init.rb` file. You can load your configuration file from there.

If you want to create a new initializer from the gem in your Rails app, you need to add a generator to your gem. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16004378/rails-how-to-create-an-initializer-inside-a-gem) question.

Comment: By reading the answer from the link you provided  It is copying the gem initializer file to the Rails application initializer correct.

Comment: I have a doubt. the init.rb you mentioned here is the hidden file in gem or something similar to twiiter_credentials.rb.

Comment: I haven't been writing about a hidden file. The init.rb and the referred question are two different shoes.